# Problema al instalar paquetes dependientes de otros en npm, error Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@4.46.0

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack

Tengo el siguiente contenido en el **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@destacame/vuetiful-widgets",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "module": "lib/index.esm.js",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build",
    "reinstall": "npm cache clean --force && rm -rf node_modules && rm -f package-lock.json && npm install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^14.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^8.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.2",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.2",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.2",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.2",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
    "@storybook/vue": "^7.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-rc.5",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "@vue/vue2-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-keys-fix": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.11",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "rollup": "^2.23.1",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.3",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.27.2",
    "rollup-plugin-vue": "^5.1.6",
    "storybook": "^7.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "sass": "^1.60.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.2",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5",
    "vue-eslint-parser": "^9.1.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.10.1",
    "@storybook/vue-webpack5": "^7.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel"
  }
}
```

Al ejecutar el comando **reinstall** este me arroja el siguiente error:

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @vuetiful-widgets@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.78.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^5.0.0" from css-loader@6.7.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/css-loader
npm ERR!     peer css-loader@"*" from @storybook/vue@7.0.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@storybook/vue
npm ERR!       dev @storybook/vue@"^7.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@storybook/vue-webpack5)
npm ERR!     peer css-loader@"*" from @storybook/vue-webpack5@7.0.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@storybook/vue-webpack5
npm ERR!       dev @storybook/vue-webpack5@"^7.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     2 more (vue-loader, @vue/cli-service)
npm ERR!   peer webpack@">=5" from babel-loader@9.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/babel-loader
npm ERR!     peerOptional babel-loader@"^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0" from @storybook/vue@7.0.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@storybook/vue
npm ERR!       dev @storybook/vue@"^7.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@storybook/vue-webpack5)
npm ERR!     peer babel-loader@"^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0" from @storybook/vue-webpack5@7.0.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@storybook/vue-webpack5
npm ERR!       dev @storybook/vue-webpack5@"^7.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   4 more (vue-loader, @vue/cli-plugin-babel, @vue/cli-service, @vue/cli-plugin-eslint)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @vue/cli-plugin-typescript@"~5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@4.46.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from cache-loader@4.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/cache-loader
npm ERR!     peerOptional cache-loader@"^4.1.0" from @vue/cli-plugin-typescript@5.0.8
npm ERR!     node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript
npm ERR!       dev @vue/cli-plugin-typescript@"~5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Según entiendo esto se debe a que hay un conflicto de versiones de webpack.
Consegui como sugerencia en un post agregando en el package.json lo siguiente

```
"resolutions": {
  "webpack": "^5.0.0"
},
```

Pero tampoco funcionó

Removí la dependencia **"@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",** del package.json y esto dejó instalar todos los paquetes, luego la instale manualmente con el siguiente comando:

```
npm install @vue/cli-plugin-typescript
```

Esto último si me funcionó

No encuentro como evitar este error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay paquetes que necesitan una diferente versión de la misma dependencia, esto genera un conflicto, ya que **podrían** generar problemas.
Recalco el "podrían", ya que la razón por la que no se instalan no es porque no sean compatibles, sino por seguridad.

Con este comando resuelves el conflicto

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

Lo que hace --legacy-peer-deps es permitir que se puedan instalar ambas versiones en tu proyecto.

**Como alternativa**

Podemos usar la propiedad "overrides" en el package.json

```
{
  "name": "@destacame/vuetiful-widgets",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "module": "lib/index.esm.js",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {...},
  "dependencies": {...},
  "devDependencies": {...},
  "overrides": { "webpack": "^5.0.0" }
}
```

Con esto todas las dependencias que necesitan webpack van a usar webpack 5, esto podría traer problemas de compatibilidad si es que utilizan alguna funcion que no esté disponible en X version.

Comment: ¿Que ventajas/desventajas da usar esta bandera? Si instalara 2 versiones a la vez ¿no estaria duplicando el peso de mi web?

Comment: Segun la documentación oficial no es recomdable usar esta 
[bandera legacy-peer-deps](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps)

Comment: Si, entiendo que estariamos empaquetando 2 versiones distintas de la misma dependencia aumentando asi el tamaño del producto final.
En vez de --legacy-peer-deps podrías usar la propiedad "overrides" en tu package.json
Override nos permite especificar que versión de una dependencia vamos a instalar en caso de que haya algun conflicto.
  "overrides": {
    "webpack": "^5.0.0"
  }
Con esto todas las dependencias que necesitan webpack van a usar webpack 5, esto podría traer problemas de compatibilidad si es que utilizan alguna funcion que no esté disponible en X version. Espero te ayude

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, no sabia esa, lastimosamente lo intenté y me dió problemas con algunas funciones.

Comment: En la documentación dice que en la versión 7 de storybook se quitó el soporte para webpack 4, si usaras la versión 6.5 tendrías soporte por defecto. Esto solucionaria los conflictos y no tendrías ningun problema de compatibilidad.
Esto aparece en https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/builders/webpack#what-about-webpack-4-support

Comment: si me sirvió, gracias.

Answer (score -1):

El mensaje de error indica que hay un problema con las dependencias de webpack. Parece que se está utilizando una versión diferente de la que se necesita para una de las dependencias. Esto puede causar problemas al intentar reinstalar las dependencias.

Hay dos soluciones posibles: una es forzar la reinstalación de las dependencias con el comando "npm install --force", pero esto podría causar más problemas. La otra opción es utilizar el flag "--legacy-peer-deps" al momento de instalar las dependencias, lo que resolverá los conflictos de una manera más compatible con versiones antiguas de npm.

**Prueba con este:**

```
  "name": "@destacame/vuetiful-widgets",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "module": "lib/index.esm.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build",
    "reinstall": "rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force && rm -f package-lock.json && npm install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^14.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^8.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.2",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.2",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.2",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.2",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
    "@storybook/vue": "^7.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-rc.5",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "@vue/vue2-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-keys-fix": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.11",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "rollup": "^2.23.1",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.3",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.27.2",
    "rollup-plugin-vue": "^5.1.6",
    "sass": "^1.60.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.2",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5",
    "vue-eslint-parser": "^9.1.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.10.1",
    "@storybook/vue-webpack5": "^7.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar: [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.

Comment: Soy de Venezuela, CHAT-GPT está fuera de mi alcance, pero si use useblackbox.io, la cual es algo similar, mis disculpas. Solo intentaba ayudar.

Answer (score -2):

Erro de dependencias al usar `reinstall`  Debe reinstalar o manual todas las dependencias o actualizarlas a la versión de webpack que esta usando:

Intente:

- Elimine node_modules y package-lock.json.
- Ejecute el comando npm cache clean --force
- npm install

Comment: esa es la definición dada en el `package.json` -> `"reinstall": "npm cache clean --force && rm -rf node_modules && rm -f package-lock.json && npm install"`

Comment: Revisar [answer].